# Accidentally deleted default EditForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365

In trying to add a script to the EditForm.aspx I appear to have accidentally deleted the default EditForm.aspx!

Is there a way of just restoring it back to how it was, I checked the recycle bin and it's not there

I'm using Sharepoint Online and Sharepoint Designer 2013

Comment: you can try to create new page using the designer...here is link for designer for 2007 but i am sure will work for 2013...follow the instruction here http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-form-HA010119111.aspx#BM2

Comment: Which recycle bin did you check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are instructions for 2007 but i am sure will work for 2013 designer.

Now open your sharepoint designer.

- Go to your list
- Go to where your newform.aspx or editform.aspx exists.
- now go & delete all the files which are not working properly.
- Now create a custom page using designer.
- now give a name to it as EditForm.aspx
- Now create a table & place a webpart zone.
- Now go t insert menu in sharepoint designer.
- In insert menu go for sharepoint controls
- Click on custom list form webpart or listform view webpart.
- you will get all the existing lists in that site.
- you will be getting 3 options.

New item form,
display item form,
edit item form.
 - Now select any one u want & press ok.

Now you get dispform webpart or editform webpart as same as u get the thing in default editform.aspx.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/03f7cc3c-aa55-468b-9060-ca302a29c290/wss30-deleted-my-editformaspx?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy